# Deploy Java Desktop application jar on server

Tags: java, deployment, server, jar, client-server

I have been developing java desktop application for SMEs.

I developed a java application for a business that needs to access SQL databases on a server. The GUI is Swing based. Now it turns out we need to deploy the java jar on the server too, so that the desktops PCs can access to it remotely and we won't be installing the jar locally as usual.

What I would like to know is if there need to be significant modification to source code I need to apply (I checked out Client/Server dev with sockets, for example), or would a simple drag n drop on the server work?

Ps. Right now I have no clue on what the server is and if it is owned by the business or hosted in a datacenter.

Also, What would the alternative be in terms of connection protocol, depending on the server location?

Comment: If this application is still a desktop application you'd need some form of remote desktop to be able to access it. Installation would depend on the environment, modifications to the application would probably not be necessary if you're just using a remote desktop.  However, the question would be if using a desktop application instead of a web application and deploying it on a server would be the best choice. This is hard to answer since we don't know the applicable requirements and constraints.

Comment: Hi Thomas, many thanks for your answer. One another following your advice: do remote desktop come with the server (eg. working on a Windows server there's a windows remote desktop panel for users to access the files, for linux another remote desktop panel etc...) or can one select the remote desktop he wants?

Comment: I'd say there are several remote desktop applications and environments, e.g. the one that comes with Windows servers or virtual desktops running on cloud. You'd need to check your infrastructure what's available or feasible.